# How can I access variables of a SpriteKit scene in another view controller?

Tags: variables, uiviewcontroller, sprite-kit

How can I access variables of a SpriteKit scene in another view controller? I am a beginner and for some reason I can't figure out how to get and set properties of different classes and scenes.

Edit:
Im sorry I was unclear. Ill try to clear things up. I have a simple little game app that has a scene where the person plays the game. After the game is over the app switches them to the game over view which is not another scene, it is just a Viewcontroller class that I used storyboards to build the interface. How can I get the score, an int in the scene, to display on the game over screen, a different view controller.

Comment: NSNotification or delegate. http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/06/06/delegation-or-notification.html

Answer (score 0):

Your question is kind of unclear to me, but ill try helping anyway. For example, SKScene has an property called backgroundColor that is SKColor type. If you want to change its value you can do both following ways.

```
MyScene.backgroundColor = [SKColor greenColor];
[MyScene setBackgroundColor: [SKColor blueColor]];
```

In the first way you are accessing the backgroundColor directly and setting its value to green.
In the second, you are calling a method called "setter" and as a parameter you passing the blue color. Every time you create a @property it creates for you 2 methods, the getter and setter of that property.The getter returns you the variable value, and the setter is used to set a value to that variable. That just an overview, there is more about it and you should google it for more information, there is a bunch of tutorial out there.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity, please see edit. I appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating a static int in your scene and add a class method to set the static value and get it.

in YourScene.m

```
@implementation YourScene

    static int score=nil;

    +(int)getStaticScore
    {
    return score;
    }

    +(void)setStaticScore:(int)new
    {
    score=new;
    }

@end
```

in YourScene.h

```
@interface YourScene : SKScene
+(void)setStaticScore:(int)new;
+(int)returnStaticScore;
@end
```

And then you add #import "YourScene.h" in every SKScene Viewcontroller and others class you need to read the score.

And you call the class method to have the score.
In gameOverScene.m for example you import YourScene.h and call

```
[YourScene returnStaticScore]; //Will return you the score 
[YourScene setStaticScore:0]; //set the score to 0 for example
```

For more information, you can search on google about singleton. 
I hope this will help you.